# Multiple htaccess redirects at once

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm having some issues with redirecting a clients website.

I have a site with a /uk directory that's being redirected to a uk sub-domain, Everything else redirects to a new URL

This all works fine, but they now need to access the old sites /uk/administrator directory. How can I exclude /uk/administrator from the other rules?

Here is my current set-up:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example.com\.com$
RewriteRule ^uk/(.*) http://uk.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newexample.com/ [R=301,L]
```

I've been frantically Googeling for the past 30min with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example.com\.com$
#Exclude /uk/administ
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/uk/administrator/
RewriteRule ^uk/(.*) http://uk.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use negative lookahead:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example.com\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^uk/((?!administrator/).*)$ http://uk.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newexample.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```